# Set baseline of flexbox elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, flexbox, baseline

Consider this HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top">
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="element">
    <div class="top">
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to line the elements up horizontally using flexbox, such that the horizontal rules align. It seems that `align-items: baseline` would do the right thing – if I could make sure the element `div`s have their baseline at the horizontal bar.

See [this codepen link](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BozWEp) for something to play around with.

How can I control the baseline of such a block element?

Comment: I think it's not possible to control which element IS the baseline. I guess you'll have to separate this in 3 : over line content / line / under line content.

Comment: There is already this separation within the `.element`. Or are you saying that I have to first list all `top`, then all `hr`, and then all `bottom` blocks? That will hardly work well with a multi-line flexbox layout.

Comment: Yes, just wrote a demo, let me post it.

Answer (score 2):

You could use multiple stacked flexboxes to achieve this, however HTML gets more complex, but it looks like the only way to pretend you set the baseline yourself.

**Demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/Paf_Sebastien/tLk1jajo/

The content over the line is in one flexbox with :

```
.overline {
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

The content under the line in another with :

```
.underline {
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: I’d like to have a closer look, but from my university network, jsfiddle.net seems to regularly timeout. I’ll have a look later!

Comment: Thanks for the codepen link. Unfortunately, this does not quite cut it: If you make it `flex-wrap: wrap;` (which I need in my use case) and it has to wrap lines, things go horribly wrong.

Comment: Indeed... Don't have other ideas except : if you set fixed width in your use case as you do in the demo, you may use `inline-block` instead (but I guess flexbox is chosen on purpose).

Answer (score 0):

> I want to line the elements up horizontally using flexbox, such that
>   the horizontal rules align. It seems that align-items: baseline would
>   do the right thing

`align-items: baseline` is not going to help you here, because you want to align different elements with respect to another element (*the `hr` as opposed to aligning same elements based on the text baseline*).

If you can work with fixed heights of your `.element`s, then without changing your markup, you could do a nested `flex` and equalize your `.top` and `.bottom`, like this:

```
.top, .bottom { 
    height: 49%; 
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.top > div, .bottom > div { flex: 0 0 auto; }
```

And then, to align the `.top` one to the bottom (i.e. close to the `hr`), you would do a `margin-top: auto`, like this:

```
.top > div { margin-top: auto; }
```

This will also play along nicely with your `flex-wrap: wrap`. Try changing the width of the fiddle pane, or window size in the examples below.

**Complete Example Snippet**:

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
.container {
    height: 320px; border: 1px solid #ddd;
    display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
}
.element {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    height: 120px; width: 200px;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.top, .bottom { 
    height: 49%; 
    display: flex; flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}
.top > div, .bottom > div { flex: 0 0 auto; }
.top > div { margin-top: auto; }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top">
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="top">
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="element">
    <div class="top">
      <div>A</div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="bottom">
      <div>B</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/vym76nyn/

**Codepen**: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbOyzE

.